# Dockerode : run omxplayer command

Tags: docker, omxplayer

I'm struggling to run a container using dockerode. I have the following command which runs perfectly when entered at the command line

```
docker run -it --rm --device /dev/vchiq:/dev/vchiq -v /media/storage:/storage video -o hdmi -p storage/tr01/TR01.mp4
```

but when I run for inside dockerode it exits immediately without errors.  I have tried a few variations as follows

First attempt...

```
docker.run(
    'video',
    ['-it --rm --device /dev/vchiq:/dev/vchiq -v /media/storage:/storage video -o hdmi -p storage/tr01/TR01.mp4'],
    process.stdout, 
    {}, 
    function (err, data, container) {}
);
```

... and second attempt ...

```
docker.run(
    'video',
    ['-it --rm --device /dev/vchiq:/dev/vchiq video -o hdmi -p storage/tr01/TR01.mp4'],
    process.stdout, 
    {
          "Binds" : ["/media/storage:/storage"],
          "Privileged" : true                
    }, 
    function (err, data, container) {}
);
```

Can anybody please advise?

Many thanks